# Unable to serve static files - DotNet Core 2.1 (MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Currently trying to make a project from last year (Core 2.1) work on a Debian/Apache machine. After building my DotNet Core app, I was having a problem where my env.ContentRootPath and env.WebRootPath where showing the respective path of my windows build machine (C:\blahbla\MyProject). So I did the following change to my configure method, specifying the path of the directory for linux.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
        env.ContentRootPath = "/var/www/admin.example.com";
        env.WebRootPath = "/var/www/admin.example.com/wwwroot";
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I thought it would result in making these working in my html pages.

`<script src="~/lib/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script>`

But now I'm getting 404 on my static files (http://localhost:5000/lib/spin.js/spin.min.js)

The file is there => /var/www/admin.example.com/wwwroot/lib/spin.js/spin.min.js 
I used chmod 755 on the all the folder to make sure its not an access thing.

It says here ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1 ) that the the tilde character ~/points to the web root.

Any ideas?

Comment: removed [tag:apache] and [tag:debian] Tags, as nothing in the question pointed to anything matching them specifically (according to tag description or available information for these environment, other than mentioning their name). Edit the question if you want to make it relevant again (but read the tag description first). Also, note the difference between `~/lib/...` and `/lib/...` in URLs

Comment: What about the fact that the app work on a windows environment, but not on my Debian machine? I tough it was relevant to the question. I will edit it as asked.